# Материнка не видит ssd

Tags: железо, ssd

Материнская плата asus A320I-K не видит m2 ssd. В биосе не появляется. (ssd samsung 970 evо plus) Биос обновлял до последней версии. Не могу только найти драйвера самсунга, есть только .exe который не подходит для установки во время установки ОС.

Так-же проводил разные "танцы с бубном" резеты биоса и т.п. "Простой" sata ssd видит. Менял материнки и ssd, пытался и на других. (есть несколько таких материнок и ssd)

Помогите либо подскажите где мне взять драйвера и как их установить?

Comment: Погуглил "asus A320I-K не видит m2 ssd" и первая ссылка на форум, там было сообщение с включением опции в биосе: https://forum.ixbt.com/topic.cgi?id=4:136382:3#3

Comment: @gil9red Это уже делал. Перегуглил все уже..

Comment: https://www.asus.com/ru/support/FAQ/1044083 отсюда то прочитали все? раз устройсв по несколько, возьмите другую пару для пробы. У меня тоже 970эво плюс, но материнка на b550 чипсете, но припоминаю тоже, что там были какие-то нюансы. Я поначалу вообще усомнился прочитав ваш вопрос, о том что а-чипсет их поддерживает, но вроде на сайте указано. Вообще руководство то изучили по эксплуатации? Процессоры то какие? в инструкции есть ограничения на этот счет.

Comment: я так понимаю вам ryzen нужен для работы, на атлонах не будет ничего

Comment: @teran Руководство изучил, у меня стоит Athlon. Походу я наткнулся на несовместимость

Comment: @teran Есть у меня комп такой связки но проц amd a6-9500 и все работает